# how to user htmlAgility pack unload the html once work done

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have use htmlAgility pack to load html working good, but after some work i need to delete the html the pack loaded, but it seem it been use by process and write protected, any ideas to unload the html?

Comment: What is write protected? Please post some code, most likely have nothing to do with htmlAgility pack, but rather your other code locking file streams (missing `using` statements).

Answer (score 1):

After processing the document just set the instance of document to null and if necesary well then use `GC.Collect()`